# From logical universal gate set to physical one, Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, universal-gates

Among the several universal gate sets, the Clifford$+T$ set seems the most important one (since it should provide fault-tolerant computing).

However, that set is logical and it differs from physical implementations, e.g. IBM processors use the gate set $\{CNOT, I, R_z, \sqrt{X}, X\}$.

Hence, my question is: how does the Qiskit framework handle the switch from a gate set, such as the Clifford$+T$, to the real one?

At [this link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12419/do-all-physical-architectures-for-quantum-computers-use-the-same-universal-gate) there's an interesting possible answer. But I'd like to get a deeper understanding of the criteria Qiskit applies.

EDIT:

I'd like to input to the Qiskit `transpile` method a simple circuit performing a control S gate:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
cs = SGate().control()
qc.append(cs, [0,1])
```

with basis gate set $\{H, S, T, CNOT\}$, i.e.:

```
new_qc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['h','s','t',cx'])
```

However, the method cannot complete the task.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Qiskit transpiler? https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html

Answer (score 2):

Qiskit has a component called [*transpiler*](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler.html). One of the task of the transpiler is to convert the circuit gates into the backend basis gates. For example:

```
new_circuit = transpiler(circuit, backend=provider.get_backend('simulator_extended_stabilizer')
```

You can set your own basis with the parameter `basis_gates`. For example:

```
new_circuit = transpiler(circuit, basis_gates=['h', 'x', ...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to use the "transpile" method with basis_gates=['h','s','t','cx'], but it doesn't work. I expected it to work since it is a universal set.

Comment: Maybe you can add your circuit to the question? It could be a bug in the basis translator, which is not complete.

Comment: I have ran into issue like this before too actually. So I have to use $U3$ gate and CNOT. But theoretically, the set $\{H, T, CNOT \}$ should be enough.

Comment: Probably related to this issue? https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/6047