# What is the shortest sequence of decomposition a given single-qubit unitary gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, programming

Given a single-qubit unitary matrix, can we find the shortest sequence of Clifford + T gates that correspond to that unitary?

According to [Fast and efficient exact synthesis of single qubit unitaries generated by Clifford and T gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5236) , which is Solovay-Kitaev decomposition, I learned single-qubit decomposition may need $O(\log^{3.97} (1/\delta))$ clifford+T gates with the accuracy $\delta$.

And later many optimization is worked on it.
For example:
[Synthesis of unitaries with Clifford+T circuits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3200.pdf)

So I want to know if there exists a shortest sequence of Clifford + T gates that correspond to decompose any single-qubit unitary into Clifford+T?
If it existed, what is commonly used in current compiler?

Comment: See link to paper in the answer to this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/how-to-approximate-rx-ry-and-rz-gates It may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the abstract of the first paper you cite (which, incidentally, is *not* Solovay-Kitaev, it's an improvement), they say

> We report an efficient synthesis algorithm, with an exact optimality guarantee on the number of Hadamard and T gates used

In other words, this is the best that can be done. It yields the shortest possible sequence. This best is $O(\log\frac{1}{\delta})$ Hadamard + T.