# Is it possible to express T, CNOT, SWAP, and CCNOT gates as a product of rotation gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I am trying to learn some basics in quantum computing and reached a place where I need to understand deeply unitary matrix decomposition.
Therefore, I am looking for some help whether literature or mathematical proofs to justify the reality of the assumption that I have.

I have seen somewhere, a H-gate and S-gate can be expressed in terms of rotated X, Y, Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any single qubit gate can be decomposed to $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ rotations.

Alternatively, you can implement that gate with series of $T$ and $H$ gates using [Solovay-Kitaev algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030). However, this is tricky in practice and the algorithm is useful rather in theoretical parts of quantum computing.

It is also possible to use decomposition of single qubit gates to $Z$ rotations, $S$ and $H$ gates. See more in [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/how-to-approximate-rx-ry-and-rz-gates) thread.

Multi-qubit gates, like $CCNOT$, can be decomposed to single qubit gates and $CNOT$ gates. Note that $CNOT$ cannot be decomposed further. You can find more on gates decomposition, both single- and multi-qubit in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) article.

Answer (score 2):

The $T$ gate, being a single-qubit gate, can be decomposed into a product of rotations by *Theorem 4.1* ($Z-Y$ **decomposition for a single qubit**) in Nielsen and Chuang. The $CNOT$, $SWAP$ and $CCNOT$ gates cannot be expressed as tensor products of single-qubit gates, which precludes expression as a product of single-qubit rotations.

If you could express them as products, then your qubits would never be entangled, and you could easily simulate your system classically by tracking the qubits independently.